# Determine and kill the process under my application is running

Tags: c#, winforms, process, kill-process

This might sound odd, but I need to find a solution to kill the process my tool is running under from the code.
I can kill all the processes having the name:

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("name_of_my_tool"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

But there might be multiple instances of the tool, and I only want to kill the current one.

So can I somehow get the id, and kill the process by it? Basically I need a suicide function.

Comment: Environment.Exit() is probably what you need.

Comment: Do I assume you've already tried Process.GetCurrentProcess() and had a problem with it?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: Why not just use Environment.Exit? Alternatively if you have a good reason to use the Process namespace, you could use Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill().

Comment: What is the difference between `Environment.Exit()` and `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()`?

Comment: Read the linked question to understand it. If you want suicide as in KILL ME RIGHT NOW NOW NOW there is also ``Environment.FailFast``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with this simple snippet?

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess();
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that. My googling skill failed to operate.

Comment: @fishmong3r :) sometimes it happens to everyone. Cheers