# Closing windows form via taskbar different to close button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms program which saves properties like its size, location, splitter bar locations &c in a properties file in hte usual way. I've noticed that whenever I close the application by right clicking on its taskbar icon and choosing 'close window', these properties don't save correctly and my application then either won't start or starts with size 0 or something.

Of course I can catch these problems and hack around them, but I would like to know what is different between closing via the form and via the taskbar, so I can handle the appropiate events.

Comment: Where do you save your properties? In FormClosing event?

Comment: You settings saving code, is it in the Close button's Click event handler, or the form's Closed event handler?

Comment: Try the form's Closed event instead of Closing.

Comment: So what is different between Closed and Closing?

Comment: Not sure, I think Closing gives you the option of canceling the close, so it probably doesn't get called in a situation where you can't refuse to close.

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: [How to properly exit a C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12977924/2596334).

Comment: Surely you can debug the Windows messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first commenter to recommend the use of Form.Closed, I'm demanding my ransom money! :-)

Comment: OK, my choice of words now seems a bit unmotivated. The OP had previously posted his own answer saying that Form.Closed worked for him, and thanking all who had helped.