# Winforms app does not shut down

Tags: multithreading, winforms

I have a Winforms app that does not shut down when we close the main form. I.e. the process stays in Windows TaskManager. Here is the main program:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ServerSimulator());
    }
}
```

The main form has this code in its InitializeComponent:

```
this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.ServerSimulatorFormClosed);
```

And in the ServerSimulatorFormClosed code there is:

```
    private void ServerSimulatorFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ThornhillServerSimulator != null)
            ThornhillServerSimulator.StopListening();
        if (RamqSimulator != null)
            RamqSimulator.StopListening();
        if (SaaqSimulator != null)
            SaaqSimulator.StopListening();
        if (DisSimulator != null)
            DisSimulator.StopListening();
        if (PharmaSpaceSimulator != null)
            PharmaSpaceSimulator.StopListening();
        if (DispenserSimulator != null)
            DispenserSimulator.StopListening();
        if (AlbertaBlueCrossServerSimulator != null)
            AlbertaBlueCrossServerSimulator.StopListening();
    }
```

Since the main form opens with Application.Run, I assume I need to call Application.Exit to close down the appliction. But where do I put it. This app has threads as well. Could it be that they are preventing the app from closing. If yes, how do I properly shut down the app?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: Well, which of those methods in 'ServerSimulatorFormClosed' is getting stuck?  Also, what happens if you comment out the entire set of calls?

Comment: Are those threads ended when calling `StopListening()`? If they don't terminate, that's what's keeping your process open.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the StopListening calls from the Closed event to the Closing event.