# Exit application by clicking button on mainform when already pop up form is running

Tags: c#

Form2 is user confirmation window,i want to close the application by stop button on mainform,but currently form2 is active and there is no dependency between form2 and mainform.How to close application ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly exit a C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application). `Application.Exit` exits the application, it doesn't matter from where you call this method.

Comment: Application.Exit also not working.form2 not allowing to click button(not cross button) on mainform.

Comment: That is because you must be opening `form2` using `ShowDialog()`. It doesn't allow to access parent untill it closes, you'll have to use `form2.Show()` to keep `mainform` in access.

Answer (score 1):

You must be opening Form2 using ShowDialog() method. Instead of that use Show() method and on MainForm button's click event call Application.Exit() method

Comment: using show() creating other problem i my application.Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Hi, if Modal form is open then you can not click on Main (Parent) form.

Comment: What is the problem with earlier solution

Comment: Please let me know the whole scenario.

Comment: if i will use show() method then continuously form2 pop-up will come one by one without giving response(button click) for checking different alert.so i am not using show() method.I am calling form2 showDialog from mainform class.

Comment: Suggestion: create a single instance of Form2 and on main form's closing event check whether you have received a response for particular alert  or not. If NOT then cancel form closing event and show Form2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
// for WinForms application
if (System.Windows.Forms.Application.MessageLoop) 
{

    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
}
```

// for Console application

```
System.Environment.Exit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is the parent window will not have focus/input until the modal window (the confirmation dialog) has finished.

So, to avoid this, just make the confirmation dialog using a custom window (instead of a common dialog / msgbox) and show it. This way if the user wants to click your main form they can (the confirmation will be on background, covered by the main window because of this).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're showing the dialog as `ShowDialog()` or showing a built in `MessageBox` which is also a `ShowDialog` that needs to be closed in order for focus to return back to main window. So what you should do is create a custom Dialog and use `dialog.Show()` method. This will allow you to interact with your main window while the dialog is open and you can click on a button to close your application regardless of the dialog being open or not. Following code should do the closing work for you

```
Application.Current.ShutDown();
```