# Visual Studio C# - X Button only closes one form rather than the whole program

Tags: c#, exit, multiple-forms

So my issue is pretty straight-forward, I have a program with a login feature, and if all goes well it will open up another form and hide itself.

My issue is that in the new form that opens, hitting the X button to close the window will only close the form but leave the other one running, along with the process.

I have a quit button that shuts down the program, but is there any way to make the X button shut down the program entirely?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly exit a C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle the `Closed` or 'FormClosed' event. This event is raised when form is closed.

use either of these when creating childform.

```
childForm.Closed += (s, ev) => Application.Exit();
childForm.FormClosed += (s, ev) => Application.Exit();
```

**Update :**

Sorry, I might have over looked the last part in question, since you have `X` button which has the `Click` event, you can simply call `Application.Exit();` on that event.

Comment: No no, I mean the close button that all windows have. Something like this? - https://i.gyazo.com/31ef37a79e36e0a47db7029980714919.png - That still throws up an error.

Comment: In that case, place _either_ of the even subscription logic after `childform` instance creation. It should work.

Comment: this.Closed / this.FormClosed

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, I notice you are doing it in the `MainForm` constructor, in this case use `this.Closed += (s, ev) => Application.Exit();`

Comment: Oh man, it took a while but we got there in the end. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Application.Exit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894(v=vs.110).aspx) in your close event handler.Also if you have created any threads you need to make sure that you convert them  to background.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Still pretty new to C# and such, how would I do this?

Comment: @MaxBox please take a look at my updated answer..It has a link in it

Comment: In your close button code just add Application.Exit()

Comment: Where can I find the close button code? I have my exit button working perfectly, but I mean the top right X on all windows. Also, if I need to make it myself, how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: private void MainForm_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

Something like that?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/c45c14a626b13c2dda79c2e1cce15160.png - Like this? Because if so, that doesn't work, hitting close still keeps the process open in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.Exit()`in your button click event handler. According to the Documentation, it terminates all message loops and closes all windows thus giving your forms the possibility to execute their cleanup code (in Form.OnClose etc).

Comment: Hey there! So really, I'm still super new to this and have no idea how I would go about doing this. I've been working with C++ Console applications for a while, I have no idea how I would.

Comment: Put this code in your **'X' button** click event handler.

Comment: Where can I find the X button click event handler? And if I need to add it myself, how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: private void MainForm_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

Something like that?

Comment: Yes.Or you can override the behaviour for some another operations.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f10397f1357dd822d8a56117a4c19293.png
https://i.gyazo.com/6647659e10ca1fd14ecbfd5a4c7a0a90.png
That's what I currently have, if I then hit close, it remains open in the background.

Comment: Then use a event handler like this:

`childForm.Closed += (s, cf) => Application.Exit();`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/1d7b4ee8440f1ba3ba9d20be75ec78e6.png - this throws up some errors, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MaxBox put that in the constructor, right after the line `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/0c64d62f34fc896a62a26a040c8a6f12.png - This still gives an error, and if I don't rename it I get this - https://i.gyazo.com/66c3cbdc04c24f47668a18c7f953a066.png

Comment: Make it as `this..Closed += (s, cf) => Application.Exit();`

Answer (score 0):

If u have Form1, Form2 and need close Form2 in Close button write

```
this.Close();
```

If need close Form1(Main) then

```
Application.Exit();
```