# Using ALT+F4 to close all forms

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

I have 2 forms, `form1` is the menu, with the buttons `start`, `settings`, `quit`, and `form2` is where the program will run.

The problem I face is that if the user uses <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> on `form2`, it closes `form2`, but `form1` runs in the background. I know I can use the `form2` `Closing` event, so it can run an `Environment.Exit(0)`, but that closing event also "activates" if I use the `form2` "Back to Menu" button, which closes `form2`. I also tried just hiding `form2` with the Menu button, but then when I need to call another `form2`, it opens up a new instance of it.

**So, in summary:** <kbd>ALT+F4</kbd> should close the whole application, not just the current form, but can't use `form2` `Closing` event, because I want to close `form2` some other way too.

Comment: Well, you could use the `KeyDown` event to detect the `Alt+F4`combination and act accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `KeyDown`event for that. Basically, you catch that key combination, tell the system that you are going to process it so it does not get passed to it and finally close the application. To close it, is always better to use `Application.Exit()` instead of `Environment.Exit`. You can see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12978034/579895) for example:

```
    private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode == Keys.F4)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            //Close your app
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Environment.Exit` should be used as last resort as it forcibly and abruptly terminates the program immediately.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are right. I just used the method OP proposed to close the application and didn't thought about it.

Comment: Thanks! And Lasse V. Karlsen, I know what it does, but when someone presses the ALT+F4 they really want to close the app. I handle the Quit button properly.