# How to close one Winform upon opening another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two Win forms in my project, one `Login` form, and the `Main` form. I have a button in `Login` form, which when clicked should open the `Main` form and close the current(Login) form.

I have tried this method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mainform frm = new Mainform();
                frm.Show();
                this.Hide();
}
```

But it only hides the current form. So even after I close the Main form, I have to manually stop debugging by pressing **Shift + F5.**

Then I have tried this following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mainform frm = new Mainform();
                frm.Show();
                this.Close();
}
```

But now, when I click the button, the `Mainform` opens and within a second, both the forms are closed, and the program stops debugging.

How do I correctly open `Mainform` from `Login` form and I don't have to stop debugging ,manually ?

Comment: What kind of forms are you using? It is definitely not ASP.NET. WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Windows Forms in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this way

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Mainform frm = new Mainform();
     frm.Show();

     this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
  }
```

and in another place you can show login form again

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
  }
```

Comment: Tried it just now. When I close the Mainform, the Login form appears again, and after closing the Login form, I have to manually stop debugging it.

Comment: show some more details code, because there is no cause for login form come again

Comment: and in mainform exit method you can use `Environment.Exit(0)` then you don't have to manually stop debugginh

Comment: Use `Environment.Exit(0)` in MainForm exit method then everything will be close and you don't have to stop debugging manually

Comment: great, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you host Form2 inside Form1.

As it seems, your application begins with Form1, and in it you then load Form2,
now you close Form1 and **expect Form2 to stay alive when you just killed its host**.

A better approach would be to initialize your application with a different form, or static class preferred, which will "last" during the lifetime of your application.

this is exactly why you get a class named **Program.cs** added to your solution, when you start a new Windows Form project.

Answer (score 0):

As @polisha989 said, you can host MainForm in Program.cs if you want terminate application when MainForm is closed or eventually reopen Loginform there.

2nd optoin is to pass reference of LoginForm to MainForm and reopen LoginForm while MainForm is closing.

3rd option is to call `Application.Exit()` while MainForm is closing. (find more here [How to properly exit a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application)