# Error While exiting windows forms

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am getting error while I am trying to handle FormClosing on

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=Error creating window handle.
>   Source=System.Windows.Forms   ErrorCode=-2147467259
>   NativeErrorCode=1406   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.CreateHandle()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   InnerException:

```
    private void F0103_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result;

        result = MessageBox.Show("are you sure you want to exit", "quite confrimation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        { e.Cancel = true; }
    }
```

I tried to change `Environment.Exit(0);` to below but I fail

```
Environment.Exit(1);


Application.Exit();
```

Comment: Is it your main form? if it's anyway closing what's the `Environment.Exit` for?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten no it's not the main from and the error is randomly show up no matter if it is same form or any other form ... `Environment.Exit` is one of suggestion I found when I searched about this problem

Comment: [How to properly exit a C# application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application)

Comment: Try using Application.Exit() if it is your main form.

Comment: @DoLoop no it's not the main form

Comment: @Steve thanks ill take a look at it