# End Application in C #

Tags: c#, close-application

As a sample below, I am using an If statement for my Application, where if you press Yes, the Application should close. I click Yes, and No, and the Application just continues regardless. Does anyone know why this might happen?

```
if (diff_ULNDOB.Any())
{
     DialogResult result1 = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Cannot proceed with Cross Year checks! Please see Workbook " + output + "." + " Do you wish to close the Application?", "Error",
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    if (result1 == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();           
    }

    Progress.Error = true;
    break;
}
```

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0);`

Comment: There's no `System.Windows.Forms` in a desktop application. Just exit the `Main()` function if you want to terminate the application, or call `Environment.Exit()` to forcefully terminate it

Comment: That `System.Windows.Forms.Application` refers to a *Winforms* application that was never created or started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly exit a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `Environment.Exit(0);` when you want to close your application.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Application.Exit()` as this is a cleaner way of doing it than `Environment.Exit(0)`.

The advantages of using `Application.Exit()` is that is will allow the form to execute any cleanup processes like `Form.OnClose` which can include closing database connections and file handlers.

`Enivornment.Exit(0)` is the same as just directly killing the process, so if you use it make sure all connections and files have been released properly.

---

Above was for Windows Forms applications. If it is a console application, the best way of exiting the application is returning the relevant exit code in the `Main` method.

Comment: Assuming this is a WinForm application, you are correct, but it seems this is just a console app.

Comment: @Neil you may be correct actually, I think the `MessageBox` threw me a little bit there!