# Exit application when exception caught on BeginConnect

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exit

I am sorry if i do/did something wrong here, this is my first question in this website.

I am trying to completly exit my application (process) when a BeginConnect throws an error (mainly SocketException).

My code right now :

```
try
{
     Socket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port), new AsyncCallback(ConnectionCallBack), Socket);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
     OnError(new ErrorEventArgs(ex));
}
```

The ErrorEvent fires, and this is where i try to exit my application :

```
if (e.Ex is SocketException)
{
     MessageBox.Show(LanguageManager.GetText("Erreur1"));
     client.Dispose();
     Application.Exit();
}
```

But then, the debug mode is still running.. or if i try it without the debug mode, i find the process still there in the task manager.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Try to extend BeginConnect with timeout : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062035/how-to-configure-socket-connect-timeout

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is with the main process still waiting for its child thread to shutdown before exiting. Try closing your socket connection using the `Close()` api, let the thread shutdown gracefully and see if the main process exits.

Documentation: [Socket.Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.close(v=vs.110).aspx)

Alternatively you can do `System.Environment.Exit(1)`, but it is a brutal way of killing the application. You generally won't have to do it that way but if you have to then use it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

> **Environment.Exit Method (Int32)**
>
> .NET Framework (current version) Other Versions    Terminates this
>   process and returns an exit code to the operating system.

Example:

```
enum ExitCode : int {
  Success = 0,
  ForceTermination = 1,
  SocketException = 2
}

System.Environment.Exit(ExitCode.ForceTerminate);
```

Comment: None of the two solutions work.. the process is still there :/ When i try the application without the server connexion, it closes the process when i hit the red "X" button, so there are no other threads used except with the Async Callback

Comment: Not sure why :/ did a quick research these guy seems to have solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554408/why-would-application-exit-fail-to-work let me know how u go with it lol